# Firebase Cloud messaging doesn't work in Apple TestFlight

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, production

I've programmed a new App in Swift including Firebase.
When I run the App via Simulator, the Cloud Messaging (Push Notifications) works. But as I submitted it to TestFlight, no Message has appeared.

I've created all Certificates (for Development and Production) to send Push Notifications.

I think theres something with the token but I have no clue what :/ Can someone help me?

Here is my Code (AppDelegate.swift)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate{

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey:Any]?) -> Bool {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
        Messaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}


func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
```

Comment: In Firebase under Project Settings, Cloud Messaging did you upload the production APNs Certificate?

Comment: @chickenparm Wow, thank you very much! :) It works now!